# 2D string Array C++: Integer Concatenation Into String

Tags: c++, string, multidimensional-array

I want to start off by saying that I have almost no experience with C++ but I am taking a college class for it this semester and was just sort of messing around so that I am a little better prepared for the class. I know a good amount of Java but almost no C++.

Basically, I want to make some integers part of a string that will go into a string 2D Array. Then I want to print out just to make sure that everything is in the array...I realize that the second for loop isn't really necessary but I put it there anyway.

My problem is that I keep getting an error message when trying to do:

```
myArray[i][j] = "(" << i << "," << j << ")";
```

Specifically, it tells me:

```
error: invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [2]' to binary 
       'operator+'
```

I don't understand this error nor do I know how to fix it...

Here is what I have.

```
int height = 5;
int width = 5;
string myArray[height][width];

for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
        myArray[i][j] = "(" << i << "," << j << ")";
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
        cout << myArray[i][j] << "  ";
    }
}
```

I just want to know how to fix the error and then I would also like to know specifically why I am getting said error. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get the error because that's not the way to concatenate strings in C++. But the message is strange, since you appear to be using `operator <<` and not `operator +`.

Regardless, use a `std::stringstream`.

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "(" << i << "," << j << ")";
myArray[i][j] = ss.str();
```

Comment: Very strange..but i understand it for the most part. Thank you very much, it definitely works by doing that.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a `stringbuilder` utility in such a way that you would be able to use it as:

```
myArray[i][j] = stringbuilder() << "(" << i << "," << j << ")";

//other examples
std::string s = stringbuilder() << 25  << " is greater than " << 5;

f(stringbuilder() << a << b << c); //f is : void f(std::string const&);
```

where `stringbuilder` is defined as:

```
struct stringbuilder
{
   std::stringstream ss;
   template<typename T>
   stringbuilder & operator << (const T &data)
   {
        ss << data;
        return *this;
   }
   operator std::string() { return ss.str(); }
};
```

Note that **if** you're going to use `std::stringstream` many times in your code, the `stringbuilder` reduces the verbosity of your code. Otherwise, you can use `std::stringstream` directly.

Comment: @Rapptz: IF you're going to use `std::stringstream` many times in your code, the `stringbuilder` reduces the verbosity of your code.

Comment: Although i think this code and the answer below is pretty much that same thing...what you have here is rather hard to understand for me as I have not seen a lot of it before. However, I am sure this works just  as the below answer works as well...the below answer is just much easier for me to understand. Thank you for answering though!